# How can I use setTimeout() functions within Mocha test cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm writing a test in Mocha / Node js and want to use a setTimeout to wait for a period before executing a block of code.

How can I accomplish this?

It appears that within a Mocha test case, setTimeout() does not work. (I am aware that you can setTimeout per test case and per test file, that's not what I need here.)

In a js file run with Node, ie, `node miniTest.js`, this will wait 3 seconds, then print the line inside the setTimeout function.

### miniTest.js

```
console.log('waiting 3 seconds...');
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('waiting over.');
}, 3000);
```

In a js file run with Mocha, ie, `mocha smallTest.js`, this will not wait, and will finish executing and exit without ever printing the line inside the setTimeout function.

### smallTest.js:

```
mocha = require('mocha');

describe('small test', function() {
    it('tiny test case', function() {
        console.log('waiting 3 seconds...');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('waiting over.')
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are forgetting to pass parameter in `it('tiny test case', function()` and call done() after console.log in setTimeout method.

```
describe('small test', function(){
   it('tiny test case', function(done){
       console.log('waiting 3 seconds');
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log('waiting over.');
           done();
       }, 3000)
   })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This runs and indeed, waits the allotted time.

Comment: Hi - why does the `done` need to be added? If there was simply a test with many steps, it it ok just to use `this.timeout = 60000` ?

Comment: @userMod2 Yes, as long as your code is synchronous, running each step one after the other, setting a timeout is sufficient. But the code in the OP (any code using `setTimeout`) is *asynchronous*, meaning that it returns immediately and the function argument gets run at a future time.

It's understandably confusing that there are two kinds of things both called "timeouts" here: `this.timeout = x` means "if my test runs longer than x ms, consider it a failure". `setTimeout(function, x)` means "after waiting x ms, run my function".

Comment: How to do this in new async await syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have done passed as a parameter in your test which will be invoked once the test passes.

You can write your test like

```
mocha = require('mocha');

describe('small test', function(done) {
    it('tiny test case', function() {
       console.log('waiting 3 seconds...');
       setTimeout(function () {
           console.log('waiting over.');
           done();
       }, 3000);
    });
```

});

This will wait 3 seconds after that it will print 'waiting over' and pass the test. You can also have a condition inside the timeout depending upon whether the condition is satisfied or not you can pass the test by calling

```
done();
```

or fail the test by either throwing an error or passing the error message in

```
done("Test Failed");
```

Comment: `done` should be passed in `it` and not in `describe`. Also it won't work.

Comment: How to do this in new async await syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Have your test function take a parameter (typically called `done`). Mocha will pass a function that you'll call in the `setTimeout` function (e.g. after `console.log` call `done()`).

See https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete example. You need to call done() in every assertion you make. You can leave out the *before* function and do the setTimeout in one of your *it* functions, but it should still use and call done() after assert.

```
var foo = 1;
before(function(done) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    foo = 2;
    done();
  }, 500)
});

describe("Async setup", function(done){

  it("should have foo equal to 2.", function(done){
    expect(foo).to.be.equal(2);
    done();
  });

  it("should have foo not equal 3.", function(done){
    expect(foo).to.be.not.equal(3);
    done();
  });

});
```

Comment: How to do this in new async await syntax?