# React Test. how to test function inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

What is the proper way to test a method within a react component, in this case componentDidMount. I want to test the setTimeOut function inside the compoenent. Should I use stub? For example the code below:

```
 componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isOpen: true }), 1);
  }
```

How can I test the setTimeout being called?

I tried with the following and didn't work. What am I missing?

```
my imports:

import test from 'ava';
import React from 'react';
import { ad } from 'components/Ad/Ad';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { stub } from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import  sinon from 'sinon';

let info;

test.beforeEach(() => {

  info = shallow(<ad {...props} />)
});

test('is active: true after mounting', done => {
  info.instance().componentDidMount()
  setTimeout(() => {
    info.state('active').should.be.true  <--line:42
    done()
  }, 0)
})
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'be' of undefined
    null._onTimeout (test/Components/Ad.unit.js:42:5)

Comment: Is `setTimeOut` your own function, or do you mean [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)? Either way, what exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: it should be setTimeout(sorry).what I want to test is if the setTimeout is being called with the right args.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to test _what_ happens, e.g. that something is opened after a period of time?

Comment: i will test that as well. but my problem is how do I call setTimeout from my test.

Comment: This is easy to do with [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) and shallow rendering.

Comment: @john_omalley do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that uses mocha, chai, and enzyme:

The component:

```
import React, {PropTypes as T} from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class FadeIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = {active: false}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({active: true}), 0)
  }

  render() {
    const {active} = this.state
    return (
      <div className={classnames('fade-in', {active}, this.props.className)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

FadeIn.propTypes = {
  className: T.string
}

FadeIn.displayName = 'FadeIn'
```

The test:

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import FadeIn from '../../src/components/FadeIn'

describe('FadeIn', () => {
  let component

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<FadeIn/>)
  })

  it('is initially active: false', () => {
    component.state('active').should.be.false
    component.find('div.fade-in').prop('className').should.equal('fade-in')
  })

  it('is active: true after mounting', done => {
    component.instance().componentDidMount()
    setTimeout(() => {
      component.state('active').should.be.true
      component.find('div.fade-in').prop('className').should.equal('fade-in active')
      done()
    }, 0)
  })

})
```

Comment: I am getting the following error.I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'be' of undefined null._onTimeout (test/Components/Ad.unit.js:42:5). see my edited question for  my test.

Comment: this example is for the 'should' syntax of [chai](http://chaijs.com/)... adjust for whatever dsl you use for assertions in mocha (assuming of course you're using mocha)

Answer (score 0):

The Mocha framework has support for asynchronous tests and allows you to use  `setTimeout` in your test as well.  Then you make your assertions within the  asynchronous callback.

```
describe('test component', function() {
    it('should have isOpen true', function(done) {
        // *** setup your component here *** 
        console.log('waiting 3 seconds...');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('waiting over.')
            // ** assert component state.isOpen == true **
            done(); // callback to indicate that test is over
        }, 3000);
    });
```

[How can I use setTimeout() functions within Mocha test cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730169/how-can-i-use-settimeout-functions-within-mocha-test-cases)