# How to properly test web socket connection with KotlinJS

Tags: kotlin, mocha.js, karma-mocha, kotlin-interop, kotlin-js-interop

I'm unable to test my code that uses a native `WebSocket`. This is the body of the test function:

```
val webSocket = WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888")
window.setTimeout({
    assertEquals(WebSocket.OPEN, webSocket.readyState)
}, 1000)
```

I'm using Karma with Mocha test runner. The following code executes without any errors, but the `setTimeout` is actually ignored and never executed.

Mocha seems to support `setTimeout`-based tests with the `--delay`. However, when I use the flag with `client: { mocha: { delay: true } }` Karma configuration, the tests just freeze and fail, outputting the following cause message:

> Disconnected, because no message in 60000 ms.

What is the correct way to execute tests with `setTimeout`? If this is tricky, is there any other way I can perform assertions on the `WebSocket` after it's fully connected? I don't use any Mocha-specific features yet, so I don't mind changing the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning Promise from your @Test function should do the trick.
Something like:

```
@Test fun testWebSocket() = Promise<Unit> { resolve, reject ->
    val webSocket = WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888")
    window.setTimeout({
        assertEquals(WebSocket.OPEN, webSocket.readyState)
        resolve(Unit)
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: The Promise support was added in 1.2.20, should work in Mocha, Jasmine, and Jest. This is not a final design, most likely there will be a more convenient way.

Comment: It would be convenient if tests could consume a `done: () -> Unit` callback, similarly to how Mocha solves this. However, I think `Promise`-based approach is the best for now, as it does not require external bindings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test async code, you need to tell the test framework when the test is done.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733027/4815713).

Comment: Yes, I eventually went with Mocha bindings and using `describe`/`it` to use the `done` callback.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to implement using `Promise`. Make the test return promise and call `resolve` when done with the asserts.